# How to use components in v-html

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to use components in v-html.
I want to get html from own API, then I will show that.

Here is my code.

HTML:

```
<!-- app -->
<div id="app">
  <span v-html="html"></span>
  <badge></badge>
  <span v-html="html2"></span>
  <partial name="my-partial"></partial>
  <span v-html="html3"></span>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
Vue.component('badge', {
  template: '<span class="component-tag">This is component</span>',
})
Vue.partial('my-partial', '<p>This is a partial!</p>')
// start app
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    html: '<p>THIS IS HTML</p>',
    html2: '<badge></badge>',
    html3: '<partial name="my-partial"></partial>'
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9w3kz6xm/4/

I tried partials because Vue document says " If you need to reuse template pieces, you should use partials."

It does not work. Maybe I am making mistake, I don't know what is a mistake.

Thank you.

Comment: When the documentation says "you should use partials", it does not mean "use partials with v-html", it means "use partials instead of v-html".

everything inserted with `v-html` will only be plain HTML, that means no components, directives, mustache tags or partials or anything Vue-specific in it will work.

Comment: Following your link, everything seems to work fine for me.

Comment: @LinusBorg I understand! Thank you! Here is my answer codes. [https://jsfiddle.net/9w3kz6xm/7/](https://jsfiddle.net/9w3kz6xm/7/)

Comment: @Ben Thank you for your comment. I got answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Pretty sure Vuejs makes it very hard to directly use external html. `v-html` will simply replace the html content and therefore will not execute any directive. The purpose of it is to avoid XSS attacks as documented here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML

> Dynamically rendering arbitrary HTML on your website can be very dangerous because it can easily lead to XSS vulnerabilities. Only use HTML interpolation on trusted content and never on user-provided content.

If you really need to use external html, it is possible to use `Vue.compile()` documented here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile

A working example can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/Linusborg/1zdzu7k1/
and its related discussion can be found here: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-compile-what-is-staticrenderfns-render-vs-staticrenderfns/3950/7

Comment: There are a few instances where v-html DIDN'T prevent XSS for me. This is an example of one that exposed a vulnerability for me when using v-html... paste this in text that gets parsed through v-html: <img/src=""onerror=alert(9)>

Comment: There is one caveat with the `compile` approach, as per Vuejs documentation `Only available in the full build`.

https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only

Comment: The answer contradicts itself. The documentation on v-html says it *allows* XSS, which is true. The same thing is called `dangerouslySetInnerHTML​` in React for a reason. The purpose of v-html is assign innerHTML in templates without compiler overhead, not to address security issues. It may be possible to prevent XSS with HTML sanitization.

Comment: @EstusFlask is right in the fact that `v-html` is not preventing anything at all here. Try to use this package rather: https://github.com/LeSuisse/vue-dompurify-html for a simple Vue-y intergration.