# Render HTML retrieved by axiom with Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In my Vue app, I have an ajax call to retrieve some HTML:

```
axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/html-example'
})
.then(response => {
   this.htmlForm = response.data;
})
```

The HTML looks like this `<h1><test></test></h1>` where `test` is a component that I have already registered in Vue.

The HTML is shown through a div:

```
<div v-html="htmlForm"></div>
```

However the component `<test></test>` is not rendered.

How can I render the HTML that I received through ajax?

## My research:

- I have been reading about [async components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html) but as far as I understand this is only to code-split your application and to actually only load the component if it is used. However, I have already registered the component in Vue, I just need to render the HTML with VUE.
- I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40695546/vue-2-render-components-from-an-ajax-response), however, there is only one answer suggesting to use async componotes, but that does not rerender anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`v-html` is designed for inserting **raw HTML** fragments into the code. Vue does not interfere with it at all.

In order to achieve what you want, you need a **full build** of Vue (i.e. compiler included) and manually instantiate the Vue instance for the template.

For example:

```
var res = Vue.compile(axiosHTML)

new Vue({
    data() {
        // Your reactive properties
        return {};      
    },
    render: res.render,
    staticRenderFns: res.staticRenderFns
}).$mount(/* htmlElementReference */);
```