# Load Vue Componet via AJAX

Tags: ajax, vue.js, components

I'd like to load Vue Component via AJAX dynamically and render its template.

Main Vue Instance:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    path: '/vue/actions/',
    mode: 'history'
});

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#mainContainer',
    router,
    data: {
        mainContent: ''
    },
    methods: {
        action: function (url) {
            alert(url);
            this.$router.push({ path: '/vue/actions/?'+url});
            console.log(this.$route.query);
        },
        actions: function () {
            var action;
            if (!this.$route.query.action || this.$route.query.action == 'main') {
                action = 'index';
            } else {
                action = this.$route.query.action;
            }
            var mainContent;
            fetch('/vue/actions/?content_type=json&action='+action).then((response) => {
                if(response.ok) {
                    return response.json();
                }
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
            }).then((json) => {
                this.$router.push({ path: '/vue/actions/', query: { action: json.action }});
                // this.mainContent = json.template;
                console.log(json.template);
                this.dynamicComponent = json.template;
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    },
    created: function () {
        this.actions();
    }
})
```

Initial Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
    <meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
    <meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/vue-router.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<template><div><component :is="dynamicComponent"></component></div></template>
<div id="mainContainer" v-html="mainContent"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Component I'd like to load via AJAX:

```
Vue.component('dynamicComponent', {
    template: '<div>Dynamic Component!</div>'
});
```

Is it possible to load such Vue Componet and render its template (with an ability to use Vue data bindings in the Component template)?

Comment: why do you want to load the component via ajax ?

Comment: @MazinoSUkah I'd like to send the component only when needed

Comment: Don't load it with ajax then maybe?  Instead just add a `v-if="someTrigger"` to the component and switch its value to true when you want the component to load.  In vue v-if  loading is 'lazy'  meaning that the component is only actual loaded when v-if evaluates to true.

Comment: @helgi sounds like u need webpack code splitting

Comment: @MazinoSUkah thank you!
looks like this is what I need:

`Vue.component('dynamic-component', (resolve) => { import('/vue/actions/?content_type=javascript&action='+action).then((component) => { resolve(component.default); }); });`

Comment: @helgi exactly, u re welcome

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use components in v-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37133282/how-to-use-components-in-v-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I got what I need:

Main Vue Instance:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    path: '/vue/actions/',
    mode: 'history'
});

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#mainContainer',
    router,
    data: {
        mainContent: ''
    },
    methods: {
        action: function (url) {
            this.$router.push({ path: '/vue/actions/?'+url});
            console.log(this.$route.query);
        },
        actions: function () {
            var action;
            if (!this.$route.query.action || this.$route.query.action == 'main') {
                action = 'index';
            } else {
                action = this.$route.query.action;
            }
            Vue.component('dynamic-component', (resolve) => {
                import('/vue/actions/?content_type=javascript&action='+action).then((component) => {
                    resolve(component.default);
                });
            });
        }
    },
    created: function () {
        this.actions();
    }
})
```

Main/Initial Page Body:

```
<body>
<div id="mainContainer">
    <dynamic-component></dynamic-component>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{.__web_root_folder}}/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Component code that I'm loading when needed:

```
export default {
    template: '<div>Async Component! {{.test}}</div>',
    data () {
        return {
            test: 'Works!'
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to @MazinoSUkah !

Comment: So unfortunately this doesn't work in Firefox (yet) Is there an alternative to this solution? Somehow binding/evaluating a JS file dynamically loaded via Ajax? I tried parsing it as JSON and that failed, as creating functions is not valid in a JSON object

Comment: @NelsonRodriguez you are right about FF and that's the most pity. I didn't find better solution that I provided. One thing that you can do is to use JS transpiler Bable or Webpack and make this code working in FF.