# Vue - Render an element out of string

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I would like to create a vue element from a string from my database.

In this case, it should be a message with a smiley emoji.
I actually save it like: `Some text with Emoji: :santa::skin-tone-3:`, and replace all valid string between '::' with the `<Emoji emoji=':santa::skin-tone-3:' :size='16' />`

```
<template>
  <span class=message v-html=convertedMessage></div>
</template>

<script>
  import { Emoji } from 'emoji-mart-vue'

  export default {
    components: {
      Emoji
    },
    computed:{
      convertedMessage(){
        return "Some text with Emoji: "+"<Emoji emoji=':santa::skin-tone-3:' :size='16' />"
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

But instead of the rendered element which should be something like:

```
<span data-v-7f853594="" style="display: inline-block; width: 32px; height: 32px; background-image: url(&quot;https://unpkg.com/emoji-datasource-apple@4.0.4/img/apple/sheets/64.png&quot;); background-size: 5200%; background-position: 15.6863% 41.1765%;"></span>
```

I only get:

```
<emoji emoji=":santa::skin-tone-3:" :size="16"></emoji>
```

What is the best possibility to render this Element like intended?

Comment: I can make a library recommendation: https://github.com/alexjoverm/v-runtime-template is a nice abstraction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use components in v-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37133282/how-to-use-components-in-v-html)

Answer (score 9):

Here are some much easier ways to do what you generally want.  If you give more specifics, your right direction may be a strategy pattern before one of these solutions, but one of these solutions is probably what you want:

1) Vue lets you dynamically define components right out of the box, so this single line:

```
<component v-for="(component, index) in components" :key="'component'+index" :is="component.name" v-bind="component.props" />
```

...would draw a bunch of components in an array of objects like this (for example): {name: 'myComponentName', props: {foo: 1, bar: 'baz'}}.

2) Vue lets you inject HTML into components by simply adding v-html="variable"

For example, here is a component that creates dynamic SVG icons, where the contents of the SVG is dynamically injected from JavaScript variables...

```
<template>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    :width="width"
    :height="height"
    viewBox="0 0 18 18"
    :aria-labelledby="name"
    role="presentation"
  >
    <title :id="name" lang="en">{{name}} icon</title>
    <g :fill="color" v-html="path">
    </g>
  </svg>
</template>

<script>
import icons from '../common/icons'
export default {
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      default: 'box'
    },
    width: {
      type: [Number, String],
      default: 18
    },
    height: {
      type: [Number, String],
      default: 18
    },
    color: {
      type: String,
      default: 'currentColor'
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      path: icons[this.name]
    }
  },
  created () {
    console.log(icons)
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
  svg {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
  }
</style>
```

3) Vue lets you dynamically define your component template through this.$options.template:

```
export default {
  props: ['name', 'props'],
  template:  '',
  created(){
    this.$options.template = `<component :is="name" ${props.join(' ')} ></component>`
  },
}
```

4) Vue lets you define a render function, so proxy components or other advanced shenanigans are trivial:

```
Vue.component('component-proxy', {
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    props: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {}
    }
  },
  render(h) {
    // Note the h function can render anything, like h('div') works too.
    // the JS object that follows can contain anything like on, class, or more elements
    return h(this.name, {
      attrs: this.props
    });
  }
});
```

A smart genius wrote a jsbin for this here: http://jsbin.com/fifatod/5/edit?html,js,output

5) Vue allows you to create components with Vue.extend or even passing in raw JavaScript objects into a page or apps components section, like this, which creates a component named "foo" from a simple string for the template and an array for props, you could also extend the data, created, on, etc. the same way using the JS object alone:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    foo: 'bar',
    props: {a: 'a', b: 'b'}
  },
  components: {
    foo: {
      template: '<p>{{ a }} {{ b }}</p>',
      props: ['a', 'b']
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Nick, can you give me some advice about inserting vue-components into content editable and what string should I store to database to recreate user input to wysiwyg vue-editor? Here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59849554/how-to-insert-vue-component-into-contenteditable-div

Comment: Sure thing! :) Answered and gave you an example codepen to play with. (https://codepen.io/njsteele/pen/wvBNYJY).

I also wrote a super simple var template parser, which will let you inject live vue components that update inside the editor, and do other cool things (https://github.com/onexdata/nano-var-template)

Opting to go the var template route will let you use shortcodes instead of HTML output (i.e. if you store the editor content in a database, it will both be smaller, and dynamic / update as you update your components).

 Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: Oh, that's great!!! I will check it tomorrow early in the morning. Thank you!

Comment: hey guys, possible to get point 4) working for vue3? I tried using the same techniques but didnt work. 
http://jsbin.com/fifatod/5/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 4):

What i figured out now:

```
convertedMessage(){
    let el = Vue.compile("<Emoji emoji=':santa::skin-tone-3:' :size='16' />")
    el = new Vue({
        components: {
            Emoji
        },
        render: el.render,
        staticRenderFns: el.staticRenderFns
    }).$mount()
    return "Some text with Emoji: "+el.$el.innerHTML
}
```

Maybe there is still a better solution to handle this?

Comment: You don't want to do this for two main reasons: First, Vue.compile adds to your build size, as it's not included by default since it's considered a build-time function. Second, compiling at runtime is "absolutely wrong for production" according to the VueJS docs. The reasoning is compiling a vue component at runtime is the slowest possible way you can render a component in Vue.

Comment: @NickSteele So how would i do such a thing if i can only return a string and not html directly? I came across this as i am trying to do something similar.

Comment: @NicoBleiler Do you mean "I can only return a string" as in from a function? I'm not sure I follow your question, but my answer here as to the ways that Vue lets you render components covers pretty much every way you can build dynamic vue components: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53752539/3196360

Comment: @jacob-graf, have you found the better solution?

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I went about when I needed to do something similar.

I rendered the component, say, `<my-component>` normally, but since I only needed rendered HTML, I wrapped it inside a `<div class="hidden">` like so:

```
<div class="hidden">
   <my-component />
</div>
```

With CSS:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

This way, I can refer to the element through `$refs` or you could get the element from the DOM using `document.querySelector()` while keeping it invisible to the end users.

So in the above example, to get the rendered HTML, You'd only need to do this:

```
let el = document.querySelector('.hidden');
let renderedHTMLString = el.children[0].outerHTML;
```

This way, you get the rendered HTML, without any overhead costs that's associated with `Vue.compile` or any other plugin. **Render it normally. Hide it. Access it's outerHTML.**

Comment: Sometimes you can't load it beforehand. For example, if you receive the HTML through ajax.

Answer (score 2):

`v-html` only render plain HTML, see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML

In your case you should probably take a look at render functions and JSX. I'm not an expert but it seems that some people are acheiving what you want with the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` JSX function. Take a look at this thread : [How do I convert a string to jsx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36104302/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-jsx)

I know sometimes we have no choice but if you can I think the best solution could be to avoid generating the template from the backend as it breaks separation of concern (and also, probably, security issues).