# How to put a component inside innerHTML in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I need to put some HTML code inside innerHTML but I have also some components that need to use like 'vue-feather-icons', I have tested many ways but I didn't find the solution yet.
my tries are

```
<div class="blog blog-block" v-html='`<div>${<ChevronLeftIcon></ChevronLeftIcon>}</div>`'>
<div class="blog blog-block" v-html='`<div><ChevronLeftIcon></ChevronLeftIcon></div>`'>
```

There is a correct way to put a componenet inside innerHtml

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use components in v-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37133282/how-to-use-components-in-v-html)

Comment: I have related question about inserting components here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59849554/how-to-insert-vue-component-into-contenteditable-div . If you will find something interesting about this, please let me know.

Comment: I think I need to ask how with nuxt js