# Return component within v-html in Vue 2

Tags: vue.js

Is there a way to return a component within the `v-html` directive?

For example:

```html
<span v-html="somethingWithAComponent"/>
```

and

```js
computed: {
  somethingWithAComponent() {
    return `'<b-icon icon="star-fill"></b-icon>'`
  }
}
```

doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use components in v-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37133282/how-to-use-components-in-v-html)

Comment: A dynamic component is better on every aspect. Using inject HTML is 99% of the time a bad idea.

Comment: The idea of `Vue` is that the data drives the `DOM` and drives the `UI`, and does not manipulate the `DOM` directly, although such a directive exists, but it is not recommended to use it

Comment: Why do not use <component> tag ?

Comment: @Loki: Interesting. I wasn't aware of this feature of Vue.

Comment: I was able to get my code to work by just converting the font-awesome icon into pure html and using that instead.  This doesn't answer my question so I'm going to leave it as a comment.  And, admittedly, it's a bit hacky, but because of additional logic needed in rendering, this was the only thing that I could get to work.

Comment: Why do you even need to do all of this? Rather than using a prop like this `<b-icon :icon="my-cool-icon"></b-icon>`?

Comment: @Kissu: Because there's a  lot of additional logic involved: https://jsfiddle.net/kreut/pfq60289/1/. The line where I'm using the html version of the icon is:   html += studentResponse.answeredCorrectly ? successIcon : failureIcon.

Comment: There is a LOT of imperative code due to the usage of Vue (that you should not be using anyway since we're already almost 2023). Hence why you need such funky practices. I recommend that you go back into using VueJS' API and have something simpler, less error-prone and with far better performance.